# Eigen matrix rowwise addition

Tags: c++, eigen

I have an Nx3 Eigen matrix representing a bunch of locations of vertices in 3d space.
I'm trying to add a 1x3 matrix to each row in the Nx3 to move every point a given direction and distance.

```
#include <Eigen/Dense>
int N = 20; //for example
MatrixXf N3(N, 3);
N3.fill(2);
MatrixXf origin(1, 3);
origin << 1, 2, 3;
```

Now I want to add origin to each row in N3 so N3 becomes 3, 4, 5 in each row. (The values in N3 are all different 3d vertex locations in the real code.)

```
3, 4, 5
3, 4, 5
3, 4, 5 etc...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may just write

```
N3 += origin.replicate(N,1);
```

note that no temporary matrix is created, `replicate()` returns an expression.

Comment: I like this answer. It doesn't require allocating any new memory.
For future reference:
`void N3plus3(MatrixXf &A, MatrixXf &B) {
 A += B.replicate(A.rows(), 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested)

```
for (int i = 0 ;  i < 3 ; i++)
    N3.block(i, 0, 1, 3) = N3.block(i, 0, 1, 3) + origin
```

I do not remember if += is supported

Answer (score 0):

`MatrixXf result = N3 + MatrixXf::Constant(1, N, 1) * origin;`

Should be simple as that.